# How to use rtd function in excel with javascript

Tags: excel, office-js

I see the `rtd` function is supported in document, see [office-js document](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/functions#list).

But I get `undefined` when I printed the `ctx.workbook.functions.rtd` .

Thanks in advance!

```
Excel.run((ctx) => {
console.log(ctx.workbook.functions.rtd); // undefined
const userLogin = ctx.workbook.functions.rtd('ExcelRtd.RQData', null, 'login', 'test', 'test');

userLogin.load('value');
    return ctx.sync()
        .then(() => {
                console.log(userLogin.value);
            });
        }).catch((error) => {
                console.log('Error: ' + error); // Error: TypeError: 对象不支持“rtd”属性或方法
                if (error instanceof window.OfficeExtension.Error) {
                    console.log('Debug info: ' + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
                }
        });
```

The result of `console` is the note after it.

Comment: Please provide a complete snippet in which you call cts.workbook.functions.rtd. Based on the code examples in the article that you linked to and on what I see here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RTD-function-e0cc001a-56f0-470a-9b19-9455dc0eb593, it seems that you need to pass at least 4 parameters to rtd.

Comment: Thank you, i had added it in my question. And I `console` the other functions like `sum`, it give me a `function` object.

Comment: Does the line console.log(userLogin.value); run? What does it return?

Comment: No, it was bloked in `const userLogin =  ...` line. Because the `ctx.workbook.functions.rtd` is `undefined`.

Comment: I can reproduce. I will report this to the product team. It's probably a documentation error to have rtd listed as a supported function.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. By the way, Is there a plan to support `rtd` in office-js?

Comment: RTD assumes COM automation which only applies to Windows. Microsoft only supports functions that can run on all the platforms for which it supports Office Add-ins. So, we do not plan to support RTD. I'll make this an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This was a documentation error which should be fixed shortly. RTD assumes COM automation which only applies to Windows. Microsoft only supports functions in context.workbook.functions that can run on all the platforms for which it supports Office Add-ins, including Mac and Office Online. So, we do not support RTD.